# How do I store a persistent history?

Tags: emacs, emacs24

Im fairly new to Emacs (I'm using emacs now since 1 month) and migrated from vim. One "feature" of vim I really miss in Emacs, is the persistent history.

When I am starting vim I can easily open files I recently had open via the command history. But in Emacs when im in dired (or executing commands via `M-x`) and then pressing `M-p` I can only browse through the sessions history, and cannot open i.e. files I had opened in a previous session. So, now my question: **Is it possible to store the Emacs-history persistent on my system**, that when I re-open Emacs I can access my complete history?
(Btw. my Emacs Version is 24.3.1)

Thanks in regards,
Niklas

Comment: Not related to the specific question, but since you're coming from Vim, take a look at [Evil](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil) if you haven't already -- very nice Vim emulation.

Comment: With helm there is `helm-recentf` to open recently open files. https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/wiki I like this combinaison of helm sources too: http://steckerhalter.co.vu/posts/emacs-helm-know-how.html

Comment: @Dan I'm already using evil. It's a georgeous tool, but not as georgeous as vim in text-editing. Im using emacs more as a tiling wm or lisp-box. It's really nice to have a "Eierlegende Vollmilchsau" which has every tool you need, with a very similar set of keybindings.

Comment: @Ehvince I must really look into helm it looks like a really nice completion framework (?). I installed it already but never get interested in using it, since it appears to need a lot of configuration. But I promise after I grok Org-Mode, I am learning helm :D

Comment: mmh it doesn't really need any config to start using it. Just call a command (it is a whole set of commands using the same completion framework). Try my favourite one now: `M-x helm-swoop`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put `(savehist-mode 1)` in your `.emacs` to save your minibuffer history over several sessions. (You will need to restart for this to work)

Comment: Uhmmm, thank you that was pretty easy. I feel a little bit supid now :D

Comment: There are a lot of small things to find in emacs had to search this in my .emacs for a while. So not a stupid question

Comment: OK that's right, Emacs is really a huge topic. When I have earned enough reputation you get an upvote from me. Have a nice day!

Comment: Note that `savehist.el` also lets you save other variables besides minibuffer histories. See also `recentf.el` for reusing names of recently used files.

Comment: You shouldn't need to restart anything for this to work. You  just need to evaluate `(savehist-mode t)` (which can be done with C-x C-e if you move the point to just after the sexp)

Answer (score 1):

For `M-x` specifically, look at the [SMex](https://github.com/nonsequitur/smex) package.  It enhances `M-x` with a history, flex matching, better ordering, etc.